# How to create dataframeSource in R? Unable to create a corpus that fits my needs

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

A beginner here.
I have a dataset of 4 columns, basically news articles, containing columns with names: **date, author, title and body** (which contains text). 
I want to create a **corpus**, but I don't understand how to create DataframeSource, basically the arguments I am passing. I understand the VectorSource. 
Thereafter my aim is to do some basic text analysis. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Becky Beck. Can you give us some more information on what you mean by ' i don't understand how to create DataframeSource'? What function from which package are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

The help of `?DataframeSource`, specifies that you need 2 columns named "doc_id" and "text". Otherwise it will fail.

So you need to create a data.frame exactly like this before continuing. If your case the data looks like this:

```
my_data <- data.frame(date = c(Sys.Date() - 1, Sys.Date()) , 
                      author = c("author1", "author2"),
                      title = c("title_1", "title_2"),
                   body = c("This is text1.", "This is text2."),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You should now get an error like below when using `DataframeSource(mydata)`:

> Error in DataframeSource(my_data) :    all(!is.na(match(c("doc_id",
>   "text"), names(x)))) is not TRUE

To solve this, you need to rename the columns title and body. For example like this:

```
index <- match(c("title", "body"), colnames(my_data))
colnames(my_data)[index] <- c("doc_id", "text")

# DataframeSource now works  
ds <- DataframeSource(my_data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try this. This may sound silly but i have 147 columns, so when writing "author1", "author2", what happens with the rest of the tags?

Comment: The rest of the columns will be put in the meta information of your corpus. You can check this with `meta(my_corpus)`. But if you have a lot of extra info you need available in your downstream information, you might want to use the quanteda package. That uses a special docvars data.frame attached to the corpus, but also available in the documenttermmatrix and token objects.

Comment: yes, actually i want to use quanteda package. is it ok to follow this tutorial : https://quanteda.io/reference/corpus.html

Comment: Also go through the examples on the example page.